# Populating a textarea in a datatable with server_processing.php

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a data table and i want a column on it to be a textarea where edits can be made, but i am finding it difficult to populate this textarea. I was able to activate the button to submit as it is not the first time i am doing it, but i feel populating the textarea wouldn't be far from it though. i would be grateful if i can get any help:

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var table = $('#admin_table').DataTable({
            //"order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline({
                url: 'server_processing.php',
                pages: 5 // number of pages to cache
            }),

           "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": 9,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<div class='w3-btn-group w3-vertical w3-center'><a id='edit_fact' class='w3-btn w3-padding w3-slim w3-small w3-black w3-text-white w3-ripple w3-card-8 w3-hover-orange w3-hover-text-black' title='Edit Fact'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil w3-center'></span></a> <a id='delete_fact' class='w3-btn w3-padding w3-slim w3-small w3-white w3-text-blue w3-ripple w3-card-8 w3-hover-red w3-hover-text-black' title='Delete Fact'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash w3-center'></span></a></div>"
            },
                    {
                "targets": 3,
                "data": true,
                "defaultContent": "<textarea name='diagnosis' id='diagnosis' ></textarea>"  
                    }        
        ]


        });

         $('#admin_table tbody').on('click', '#edit_fact', function () {
            var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
//Where i submit my edits
            });

// Populating the text area
            var data = table.row( $('#admin_table).parents('tr') ).data();
            $('#diagnosis').val(data[3]);

    });
```

what my table looks like:
[My datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxjZw.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes i manage to get it to work using `render`

Here is the code:

```
var table = $('#admin_table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline({
            url: 'scripts/server_processing.php',
            pages: 5 // number of pages to cache
        }),

       "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": 9,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<div class='w3-btn-group w3-vertical w3-center'><a id='edit_fact' class='w3-btn w3-padding w3-slim w3-small w3-black w3-text-white w3-ripple w3-card-8 w3-hover-orange w3-hover-text-black' title='Edit Fact'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil w3-center'></span></a> <a id='delete_fact' class='w3-btn w3-padding w3-slim w3-small w3-white w3-text-blue w3-ripple w3-card-8 w3-hover-red w3-hover-text-black' title='Delete Fact'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash w3-center'></span></a></div>"
        },
        {
            "targets": 3,
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return "<textarea name='diagnosis' id='diagnosis' >"+data+"</textarea>";
                }  
        }        
    ]


    });
```